# Where's my Win8 go?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-8

Got a brand new Fujitsu LifeBook AH532 laptop with Win8 pre-installed..

Yeah, right.. First thing I did was to install Ubuntu 12.10 64Bit..

Disabled "Secure Boot" in settings and voila! Well, the Ubuntu installation didn't see my Win8 partition, so I created a new partition-table to use with Ubuntu. So far so good.

After installation completed successfully, I ran "Boot-Repair" from the Live USB. Got the GRUB on boot (Booted directly to Win8 first) and could boot Ubuntu. Next thing in GRUB menu is Ubuntu Advanced settings and System settings. At this point I didn't think about it because I wanted to only use Ubuntu.

When I decided to boot win8 (for fun) I select "System Setting" in the GRUB and I get into "BIOS". There I go to "Boot" section and select "Windows Boot something" and restarts. Now I got the GRUB menu again. In BIOS again I enabled "Secure Boot", then I got som failure boot thing.. So I changed back to normal again.

My HDD is 500GB, and ca 40GB don't show in GParted, is there a chance that this is Win8? Cant see it.. Or have I deleted Win8 completely?? I dont care, just want to know..

Comment: Can you post your current partition table?

Comment: The partition table is a GPT. _1:_ **/dev/sda1 mounted as /boot/efi**    _2:_ **/dev/sda2 mounted as /** _3:_ **/dev/sda3 mounted as SWAP** _4:_ **Not allocated..** Sorry, don't know a way to copy\paste from terminal since fdisk cant list GPT... 1 is 94MB 2 is 460 GB, 3 is 5.90 GB and 4 is 1.02MB...

Comment: If either of the answers below are correct, please mark that answer as correct.

Comment: Have not tested, yet :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, unfortunately, you deleted your version of Win8.

Comment: Thought so! Nice! :P

Comment: Hm.. It cant be gone.. After installation of Ubuntu it booted directly to Win8 ???

Comment: That's true. Perhaps you removed it from the partition table, or you somehow erased something important during installation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable SecureBoot. If your BIOS allows it, also disable FastBoot and/or IntelSRT.
2. boot on a 64bit live-disk (eg from Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit), and from it run [Boot-Repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair) --> `Advanced Options` --> tick `Restore EFI backups` --> Apply. Write on a paper the URL that will appear.
3. In your BIOS, select `Boot` then `Windows Boot something`. This should boot Windows. Then if you want to boot Ubuntu, in your BIOS select `Boot` then `Ubuntu`.

Comment: Ok, can I run Boot-Repair from my Ubuntu install or must I run it from the Live USB? And for booting Ubuntu again I have to run Boot-Repair another time to make it as it is now? :)

Comment: I edited my answer. If you want more info, please indicate the URL provided by Boot-Repair.

Comment: Nothing called `Restore EFI backups` in Boot-Repair..

Comment: Log from Boot-Repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5845037/